# Wordpress Show custom post type specific category in post page?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am new in development. I have created a custom post type manually, which is as in the code given below. I am unable to get post form specific category (Logo, Website) in Custom post type. Help me to solve this.

```
function my_custom_taxonomies(){
    $lables = array(
        'name' => 'Type',
        'singular_name' => 'my_custom_taxonomiesType',

        'all_items' => 'All Types',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add Type',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Type',
        'search_item' => 'Search  Type',
        'parent_item' => 'Parent Type',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Type',
        'update_item' => 'Update Type',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Type Name',
        'menu_name' => 'Type'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $lables,
        'query_var' => ture,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'type'),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,

    );
    register_taxonomy('type', array('portfolio'), $args);
}

add_action('init','my_custom_taxonomies');
```

I am trying this code, but cannot get it to work.

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'category_name' => 'logo', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    </ul>

    <?php echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    //the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Can you confirm if your Category slug name as "logo"

Comment: http://ex/ample.com/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=type&tag_ID=13&post_type=portfolio&wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit-tags.php%3Ftaxonomy%3Dtype%26post_type%3Dportfolio

Comment: this is url of specific category http://example.com/type/logo/

Comment: Just confirm it and Can you run the `WP_Query()` by removing `'category_name' => 'logo'` and check are you getting results first of all

Comment: if i remove 'category_name' => 'logo' it show the all posts. Which i created in Custom  Post Type.

Comment: Just try the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Use this as you have registered  taxonomy. You can refere about WP_Query [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'type',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'logo',
        )
    ),
) );
```

Comment: Welcome @Gagau :-). Please upvote this too,so that it might be useful to others